# find closest position of asteroids c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

[image]

In the above image i would like to know how to find the smallest possible way to get to the asteroid.  the ship can wrap around so the closest way is going through the top corner instead  of turning around and going back.  I am not looking for code, just the pseudo code of how to get to it.

Any help is appreciated

The game asteroid is played on the surface of a torus.

Comment: I think some details are missing. Otherwise, just follow a straight line to the asteroid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, since you can wrap around any edge of the screen, there are always 4 straight lines between the asteroid and the ship (up and left, up and right, down and left, and down and right).  I would just calculate the length of each and take the smallest result.

```
int dx1 = abs(ship_x - asteroid_x);
int dx2 = screen_width - dx1;

int dy1 = abs(ship_y - asertoid_y);
int dy2 = screen_height - dy1;

// Now calculate the psuedo-distances as Pete suggests:
int psuedo1 = (dx1 * dx1) + (dy1 * dy1);
int psuedo2 = (dx2 * dx2) + (dy1 * dy1);
int psuedo3 = (dx1 * dx1) + (dy2 * dy2);
int psuedo4 = (dx2 * dx2) + (dy2 * dy2);
```

This shows how to calculate the various distances involved.  There is a little complication around mapping each one to the appropriate direction.

Comment: Easiest way.  Just use Pythagoras' theorem.  However, you can compare the squared lengths for efficiency.

Comment: @Pete The issue comes with the wrap

Comment: I'm not sure if you actually need to check all 4 directions. You can probably just check the horizontal and vertical direction separately. No need to do squares then either

Comment: @Toad not sure it would work for all cases but I might be mistaken.

Comment: thanks for your help and to everyone who gave input into this.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Toad: I believe you're right. The shortest of those four distances will always be the one with both the smallest x and the smallest y distances. Also, it occurred to me that there are really infinitely many ways to reach the asteroid, but you will never need to move more than (screen width / 2, screen height / 2) to get there, so the shortest distance is guaranteed to be one of the four I gave.

Comment: @AlanFletcher see my answer below for the more efficient version.  :)

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)

Comment: I guess because this has nothing to do with pathfinding around a map

Comment: This answer would be slightly less than perfectly efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Find the sphere in reference to the ship.

To avoid decimals in my example. let the range of x & y = [0 ... 511] where 511 == 0 when wrapped

Lets make the middle the origin.

So subtract vec2(256,256) from both the sphere and the ship's position

sphere.position(-255,255) = sphere.position(1 - 256 ,511 - 256);

ship.position(255,-255) =  ship.position(511 - 256, 1 - 256)

firstDistance(-510,510) = sphere.position(-255,255) - ship.position(255,-255)

wrappedPosition(254,-254) = wrapNewPositionToScreenBounds(firstDistance(-510,510)) // under flow / over flow using origin offset of 256

secondDistance(1,-1) = ship.position(255,-255) - wrappedPosition(254,-254)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Scalar>
struct vector2d {
  Scalar x;
  Scalar y;
};
template<typename Scalar>
struct position2d {
  Scalar x;
  Scalar y;
};

template<typename S>
S absolute( S in ) {
  if (in < S())
    return -in;
  return in;
}

template<typename S>
S ShortestPathScalar( S ship, S rock, S wrap ) {
  S direct = rock-ship;
  S indirect = (wrap-ship) + (rock);
  if (absolute( direct ) > absolute( indirect ) ) {
    return indirect;
  }
  return direct;
}

template<typename S>
vector2d<S> ShortestPath( position2d<S> ship, position2d<S> rock, position2d<S> wrap ) {
  vector2d<S> retval;
  retval.x = ShortestPathScalar( ship.x, rock.x, wrap.x );
  retval.y = ShortestPathScalar( ship.y, rock.y, wrap.y );
  return retval;
}


int main() {
  position2d<int> world = {1000, 1000};
  position2d<int> rock = {10, 10};
  position2d<int> ship = {500, 900};
  vector2d<int> path = ShortestPath( ship, rock, world );
  std::cout << "(" << path.x << "," << path.y << ")\n";
}
```

No point in doing crap with squaring stuff in a simple universe like that.

`Scalar` support for any type that supports `a < b`, and default construction for a zero.  Like `double` or `int` or `long long`.

Note that copy/pasting the above code and handing it in as an assignment at the level of course where you are playing with that problem will get you looked at strangely.  However, the algorithm should be pretty easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the smallest way to the asteroid, you don't need to calculate the actual smallest distance to it. If I understand you correctly, you need the shortest way not the length of the shortest path.

This, I think, is computationally the least expensive method to do that:

Let the meteor's position be (Mx, My) and the ship position (Sx, Sy).
The width of the viewport is W and the height is H. Now,

dx = Mx - Sx,
dy = My - Sy.

if abs(dx) > W/2 (which is 256 in this case) your ship needs to go LEFT,
if abs(dx) < W/2 your ship needs to go RIGHT.
IMPORTANT - Invert your result if dx was negative. (Thanks to @Toad for pointing this out!)

Similarly, if
abs(dy) > H/2 ship goes UP,
abs(dy) < H/2 ship goes DOWN.
Like with dx, flip your result if dy is -ve.

This takes wrapping into account and should work for every case. No squares or pythagoras theorem involved, I doubt it can be done any cheaper. Also if you HAVE to find the actual shortest distance, you'll only have to apply it once now (since you already know which one of the four possible paths you need to take). @Peter's post gives an elegant way to do that while taking wrapping into account.

Comment: this is incorrect. Suppose Sx=2 and Mx=1 then the ship should go left. however according to your formula: dx = Mx - Sx  = 1 - 2 = -1   which is smaller than W/2 so it would go to the right

Comment: Funny... The dry-run in my head worked fine :) I must have missed something. Hmmm... Gimme a sec to think about this again

Comment: Okay I missed the part where you have to flip your result. Thanks for pointing it out. Have edited the original post.